# Finding basis for eigenspace when RREF returns several non-zero rows

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a matrix A:

$ \left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 1 & 3\\
1 & 3 & 1\\
3 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right). $

The eigenvalues are 5, 2 and -2.

Now I have trouble with the eigenvalue 2, when finding a basis (the way I learnt to do it usually) for the eigenspace i get:

$ \left(\begin{array}{aaa}
    -1\\
    0\\
    0
    \end{array}\right).$

and

$ \left(\begin{array}{aaa}
    -1\\
    -2\\
    1
    \end{array}\right).$

Now according to the answer sheet, the answer is supposed to be one vector only which is different from both of mine, why? Now I can't understand what Im doing wrong or how to get the right answer. There is obviously something Im missing here, but what is it.

$ \left(\begin{array}{aaa}
    1\\
    -2\\
    1
    \end{array}\right).$

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You, of course, need to find $[2 \cdot I - A]$.  What did you get for the reduced row echelon form?

Comment: You can't find more two linearly independent eigenvectors for the eigenvalue $2$: an eigenspace has dimension at most equal to the multiplicity of the eigenvalue as a root of the characteristic polynomial. Since you have $3$ eigenvalues in dimension $3$, all eigenvalues are simple.

Comment: You may want to explain how you got each e.vector so that, if you're mistaken, someone can explain where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found that in case you get a 2 vectors when row reducing to reduced echelon form, you use Gram Schmidt on both vectors as follows.

IOW: to reduce these 2 results to one we use Gram Schmidt and the result of this subtraction is the vector we use as our basis for the eigenspace which here is $ \mathbf{w}_{3} $. We use our eigenvectors $ \mathbf{w}_{1} and \mathbf{w}_{2}$ in combination with GS:
$ \mathbf{w}_{2} - \dfrac{ \mathbf{w}_{2}\cdot\mathbf{w}_{1}}{{\mathbf{w}_{1}}\cdot{\mathbf{w}_{1}}} \mathbf{w}_{1} = \mathbf{w}_{3} $